# SQL select two rows in one table generating independant output

Tags: sql

I would like to generate an output, where I count two rows from the same table but with different conditions.

Now I have this SQL Statement which works:

```
select Datum, Count(ID), Count(Fläche)
FROM gustavo
where Fläche > 200
Group by Datum;
```

but it only gives me the sizes over 480 and the id's over 480 in both rows. In the first row I would like to have the count of all IDs though. Any idea how that would work?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not checked)

```
SELECT 
   Datum, 
   COUNT(ID) all_ID , 
   SUM(if(ID>480) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IF)  ID_480,
   Count(Fläche) all_Flache
FROM 
    gustavo
WHERE 
   Fläche > 200 
GROUP BY 
   Datum;
```